# How to read a command from package.json from a Jenkins file

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a package.json

```
"scripts": {
"pact:tests": <script>
}
```

I need to check if pact:tests exists in the package.json from JenkinsFile(Groovy). If it exsits run pact test else skip it.

Tried a couple of ways

```
def pactExists = sh "grep \"pact:tests\" package.json | wc -l"
if(pactExists > 0)
   run pact
else
  skip
```

But the above code return pactExists = null

Try 2 :

```
def pactExists2 = sh "${grep pact:tests package.json}"
```

But this directly runs the command I think

Try 3 :

```
def packageJSON = readJSON file: 'package.json'
def pactExists = packageJSON.scripts.pact:tests
```

But I get an error for using ':' after pact:

Is there a way to save the output in some var?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to capture the result of the `sh` step, you need to set `returnStdout` option to `true`, e.g.

```groovy
def pactExists = sh(script: "grep \"pact:tests\" package.json | wc -l", returnStdout: true)
```

Alternatively, if you want to use `readJSON` step, then you would need to define a key using quotes, e.g.

```groovy
def pactExists = packageJSON.scripts.'pact:tests'
```